# Get max and min of array axis, and then reshape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with lines defining several polygons as:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4
.
.
.

etc
```

I would like to read them into a numpy array with one axis having the same shape as the number of polygons (ie. boxes) and the others like like:

```
[x_min,y_min],[x_min,y_max],[x_max,y_max],[x_max,y_min]
```

where x_min is the minimum x coord, x_max is the max etc.

I can read in and get the max and mins with:

```
boxes_x = np.loadtxt(label_path,usecols=np.arange(0,8,2),dtype=int,delimiter=",")
boxes_y = np.loadtxt(label_path,usecols=np.arange(1,8,2),dtype=int,delimiter=",")

 x_max = boxes_x[:].max(axis=1)
 y_max = boxes_y[:].max(axis=1)
 x_min = boxes_x[:].min(axis=1)
 y_min = boxes_y[:].min(axis=1)
```

But shaping them into the correct shape i.e [num_boxes,4,2] is proving difficult.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a non-ambiguous and reproducible numerical example?

Comment: Also please clarify the output, to you want to mix min/max? How? or it is just a typo? Again, please be explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file into `boxes` at once:

```
boxes = np.loadtxt(label_path, dtype=int,delimiter=",")
```

Suppose `boxes` represents 4 entries(polygons):

```
array([[15, 10, 20, 31,  6, 28, 23,  3],
       [30, 24,  7, 13, 24,  4, 29, 20],
       [ 1,  7,  0, 14,  2, 11,  6, 24],
       [15, 18,  7,  7,  1,  1, 21, 13]])
```

Find `min` and `max` for *x* and *y* coords respectively:

```
x_min, x_max = boxes[:, ::2].min(1), boxes[:, ::2].max(1)
y_min, y_max = boxes[:, 1::2].min(1), boxes[:, 1::2].max(1)
```

Build the output array of the needed structure and shape:

```
out_boxes = np.dstack([x_min, y_min, x_min, y_max, 
                       x_max, y_max, x_max, y_min]).reshape(-1, 4, 2)
```

Sample output:

```
array([[[ 6,  3],
        [ 6, 31],
        [23, 31],
        [23,  3]],

       [[ 7,  4],
        [ 7, 24],
        [30, 24],
        [30,  4]],

       [[ 0,  7],
        [ 0, 24],
        [ 6, 24],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 1,  1],
        [ 1, 18],
        [21, 18],
        [21,  1]]])
```

---

```
out_boxes.shape
(4, 4, 2)
```